# JSON.parse returning [Object] instead of value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonparser

I'm using **JSON.parse** to parse my JSON and retrieve the below two values but when I use `JSON.parse(test)` its returning as **[Object]** instead of actual value which is **success**

```
results.createSubProd.successSubProdct.status
results.createSubProd.failureSubProdct
```

Please find my code below:

```js
var test = '{"name":"Mark","age":"20","params":{},"results":{"createProduct":{"status":"success","desc":"test"},"addProduct":{"status":"success"},"createSubProd":{"successSubProdct":{"status":"success"},"failureSubProdct":{"status":"success"}},"addToCache":{"status":"success"}}}'
console.log(JSON.parse(test))
```

Output:

```
{
  name: 'Mark',
  age: '20',
  params: {},
  results: {
    createProduct: { status: 'success', desc: 'test' },
    addProduct: { status: 'success' },
    createSubProd: { successSubProdct: [Object], failureSubProdct: [Object] },
    addToCache: { status: 'success' }
  }
}
```

Why its returning [Object] like this `createSubProd: { successSubProdct: [Object], failureSubProdct: [Object] }` instead of `createSubProd: { successSubProdct: {"status": "success"}, failureSubProdct: ""status": "success"" }`

What's wrong here, could you please help me witht this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON.parse. Node.js just limits the depth that it will show in console.log.